# How do I unmount a bound /proc in a "dead" chroot?

Tags: mount, chroot

I built a debootstrap chroot and bound /proc to it, i.e. `sudo mount -o bind /proc <chroot>/proc`

When I found I no longer needed it, I quite stupidly `rm -r <chroot>`'d it. Of course, rm refused to remove /proc.

Now umount says that /proc is in use and cannot be unmounted. How do I unmount it, now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux refuses to remove a directory that is a mount point, so `<chroot>/proc` should still exist. And Linux refuses to remove a directory that is not empty, so `<chroot>` should still exist.

Taking what you wrote at face value, you tried to unmount `/proc`, not `<chroot>/proc`. So the kernel tried to unmount the `none` filesystem mounted on `/proc`. You should unmount the `none` filesystem mounted at `<chroot>/proc` with `umount <chroot>/proc` then `rmdir <chroot>/proc <chroot>`.

Note that if you moved `<chroot>`, you must pass the new name to `umount`. You can check what the kernel thinks is mounted by looking in `/proc/mounts`.

In case `umount` complains because your `/etc/mtab` has somehow gone out of sync, use `umount -n`.

If even `umount -n <chroot>/proc` doesn't work, it's probably because some process is still running inside the chroot to access it. Use `lsof` to locate the process and kill it.

Comment: Thanks.

Yes, `<chroot>/proc` and, by extension, `<chroot>` still exist.

And actually, I did try to unmount `<chroot>/proc`. For instance:

`_@_:~$ sudo umount -n <chroot>/proc/
[sudo] password for _: 
umount: <chroot>/proc: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))`

And then, the only process that `lsof` comes up with is `lsof` itself:

`_@_:~$ lsof <chroot>/proc/
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
lsof    7046 _    3r   DIR    0,3    0    1 <chroot>/proc/`

Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the cruddy formatting; I'm new to markdown and have made too many edits to fix it.

Comment: @brian4work: `lsof <chroot>/proc/` only shows processes that are using the `<chroot>/proc` directory. `lsof +f -- <chroot>/proc` shows all processes using the `proc` filesystem (i.e. it's equivalent to `lsof +f -- /proc`), whether through the chroot or outside (`mount --bind` is peculiar sometimes). At least `lsof +f -- /proc` would narrow the search.

Comment: Thanks so much; that did the trick. It turned out to be daemonized `dd` holding on to the chroot's kmsg file.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating the  directory then umount it?

Comment: Thanks. The directory <chroot>/proc still exists, though.